# Background color <td> + INSERT Mysql

Tags: php, css, mysql

I am playing around with PHP, however I am stuck on this part. I created a table which inserts all the information from the MySQL database, this is working perfectly, however: I want if the 'type' in the MySQL database is 1 that the entire of the table has a red background and if it's something else, it should be a green background.

Could anybody give me advise, where to start?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['type'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['transaction'] . "</td>";
    echo "</td>";
}
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Make a CSS rule and apply the class to the element based on value.

Comment: you wish to apply to each row or the entire table?

Comment: I want to apply it to each row that contains type: 1

Answer (score 2):

You need to mark the rows you want to effect somehow. You could do this with a `data-type` attribute, but if you are just starting and want to keep things simple, a `class` is the most straightforward.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr class=\"type" . $row['type'] . "\">";
    echo "<td>" . $row['date'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['type'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['transaction'] . "</td>";
    echo "</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Then within a stylesheet or `<style>` tag you can add

```
.type1 {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your code to place a condition in the 'type' 'td' :

```
echo "<td";
if($row['type'] === 1){
    echo "class=\"redbg\";
else
    echo "class=\"otherbg\";
echo >" . $row['type'] ."</td>";
```

Or, simply :

```
echo "<td";
if($row['type'] === 1){
    echo "class=\"redbg\";
echo >" . $row['type'] ."</td>";
```

Then make a standard rule in your css for td:not(redbg).